# python arrays getting the max and storing the index

Tags: python, spyder

I have a list of arrays like:

```
array([[ 0.39703756,  0.60296244],
       [ 0.47432672,  0.52567328],
       [ 0.9785825 ,  0.0214175 ],
       ..., 
       [ 0.98861711,  0.01138289],
       [ 0.98769643,  0.01230357],
       [ 0.99783641,  0.99783641]])
```

I use the below code to get the max of each row and turn it in to a list:

```
scores=scores.max(axis=1).astype(float)
scores=scores.tolist()
```

I get the maximum of each row and am able to turn it to a list. additionally, I want to know which column is the maximum in. i.e. for the first row max is 0.60 and it should say 1 and so on and so forth. However, I wasn't able to do this how can this be done?

Comment: have a look at [`numpy.argmax`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.argmax` function. This outputs the **indices** of the maximum rather than the maximum values themselves. Since this output indices, they will be integers and you don't need the `.astype(float)`

```
import numpy as np

scores=np.array([[ 0.39703756,  0.60296244],
       [ 0.47432672,  0.52567328],
       [ 0.9785825 ,  0.0214175 ],
       [ 0.98861711,  0.01138289],
       [ 0.98769643,  0.01230357],
       [ 0.99783641,  0.99783641]])

scores_max=scores.max(axis=1).astype(float)
scores_arg=scores.argmax(axis=1)
scores_arg=scores_arg.tolist() 
print(scores_arg)
```

Comment: This gives me a single number, which is 34392

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.argmax` for this, for example:

```
x = numpy.array([[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 1]])
numpy.argmax(x, axis=1)
```

will return:

```
array([2, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

for me the solution was similar to above but with a slight change

```
array([[ 0.39703756,  0.60296244],
       [ 0.47432672,  0.52567328],
       [ 0.9785825 ,  0.0214175 ],
       ..., 
       [ 0.98861711,  0.01138289],
       [ 0.98769643,  0.01230357],
       [ 0.99783641,  0.99783641]])  

scores_arg=scores.argmax(axis=1)
scores_max=scores.max(axis=1).astype(float)
scores_arg=scores_arg.tolist()
```